# Empty array returned when calling AlphaVantage APIs for NSE symbols tickers

Tags: alpha-vantage

I cannot get any NSE Symbol data from the AlphaVantage, they return always empty array.

Query:

```
https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=TIME_SERIES_INTRADAY&symbol=NSE:TITAN&apikey=Q134IXR7RVWU5AQL&outputsize=full&interval=1min
```

Response:

```
{}
```

A month back the same query was returning data.
Looks something has changed on the AlphaVantage server end recently.

Your help is much appreciated in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import pandas as pd
import json
import requests
import datetime
from pandas import DataFrame
from datetime import datetime as dt
from alpha_vantage.timeseries import TimeSeries


stock_ticker = 'SPY'
api_key = 'Q134IXR7RVWU5AQL'

ts = TimeSeries (key=api_key, output_format = "pandas")
data_daily, meta_data = ts.get_intraday(symbol=stock_ticker, interval ='1min', outputsize ='full')

print(data_daily)
```

The output for me looks like this
[image]